# Collect the nodes of a binary tree, on a given level

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

Collect the nodes at a given level in a list.  A node of a binary tree is at level *N* if the path from the root to the node has length *N-1*. The root node is at level *1*. Write a predicate `blevel/3` to collect all nodes at a given level, in a list.

This is my code in Haskell. I don't know where it is wrong:

```
-- Problem 5: BTree levels 
blevel :: Int -> BTree -> String
blevel _ Empty = ""
blevel n (Branch v tl tr)
  | n == 1 = [v]
  | n > 1 = n-1 (blevel tl)  ++ n-1 (blevel tr)
  | otherwise = ""
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: To format your code correctly copy and paste it into the editor, select it, and press the button that looks like `{}`.

Comment: You have the right idea but your Haskell syntax on the `n > 1` line is hopeless. `n - 1 (blevel tl)` means `n - (1 (blevel tl))`. I suspect you do not want to call `1` as a function and you mean to write `blevel (n-1) tl ++ ...`

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code, your data type is

```
data BTree = Empty | Branch Char BTree BTree
```

Just fix your syntax, as

```
    | n > 1 = ((n-1) `blevel` tl)  ++ ((n-1) `blevel` tr)
```

, that's all.

BTW `blevel/3` is indicative of Prolog, not Haskell.